# Date format changing in PHP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to change date format in my PHP MySQL but could not change.

```
echo ($row->PasscreationDate);?>
```

`PasscreationDate` is the date I want to change it appear default as `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`, I want to change that date format as `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
echo date('D-M-Y', strtotime($row->PasscreationDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **date_format**?

Example:

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
echo date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');
?>
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/datetime.format.php

Comment: By putting this 
echo date('D-M-Y', strtotime($row->PasscreationDate));

I got this result:
Mon-Aug-2020, (No date in number) Please help more

Comment: Try putting lowercase letters for D and M? Example: d-m-Y